# Alternatives to IIS SMTP service

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, smtp

I am using local IIS 6.0 SMTP service to send emails from ASP.NET application.
I am having the following issues:

1. Emails are being delayed from 1 hour to 24 hours, and our traffic is only increasing
2. No UI to quickly see what is going on. How many emails sent. Bad Emails, Queue, etc...
3. Have to install IIS 6.0 just to run SMTP service. Microsoft didn't include it in IIS 7.0, so not sure if they will be supporting it in the future.
4. Seems to send emails in single thread (not sure about this one).

I could use one of the cloud services like Amazon Simple Email, but it would cost me hundreds of dollars a month.  I would like to keep it local since our hosting provider has plenty of bandwidth.

What are the alternatives to IIS 6.0 SMTP service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options available to you as I see it but each has their own pro's and cons.

1. A local mail server application (eg: Exchange server) to manage your mail queue

   - pro - you retain total control
   - con - you retain total responsibility
   - con - depending on the email type and volume you could end up getting blacklisted
2. A cloud mail provider that you are obviously aware of.
3. Arrange with your ISP to direct smtp traffic directly through them rather than using your own smtp service which is forwarded through them anyway. They also may have tools that will allow you to view and control the traffic.

Good luck

AJ